# jquery callback is not getting fired

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp, struts2

I have been trying to display json data in my jsp using struts and json. I am using jquery  post to send the data to the action class, on success, it should fire a callback function is jquery post.But the callback is not fired.

I am unable to find the missing link in this.

Here are my codes..

My struts xml..

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

   <struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"></constant>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources"></constant>

<package name="default" extends="json-default">

  <action name="some" class="action.Testing">
    <result type="json">
     <param name="root">displaying</param>
     <param name="noCache">true</param>
    </result>

  </action>

 </package>

 </struts>
```

My jsp page is the following..

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/json.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js"></SCRIPT>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function somecallback(displaying){


     var result = displaying.split(",");

  var dataintext = result[0];

    $('#sub').val(dataintext);

   }


  function test(){

    var input = { "text" : "testing entry data",
               "displaying" : "hello"
            };  

       $.post('some.action',input,somecallback,"json");
  }

    $(function(){
    $('#field').click(function(){
     test();
     return false;
     });

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <s:form method="post">
 hello..
<s:submit id="field" value="click me too!!"></s:submit>
<s:textarea id="sub" name="tes" value="%{text}"></s:textarea>
<s:textarea id="second" name="tester"></s:textarea>
<div id="flag" style="height:100px;width:20px;">sfdsf</div>
<input type="text" id="hi" name="help" value="clicked here!!" />"
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Suggestions and help greatly appreciated..

Thank you,
hemanth.

Comment: Since you are including three different scripts did you check whether any one is defining the jquery object in a different manner (like using the '$' sign)? May this post might of little help to you --> [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822248/using-jquery-getjson-with-other-javascripts-included-gives-referenceerror

Comment: '$' is wrapped around 'jquery', in both the js...

Comment: @hemanth Please update your post to reflect the current code that doesn't work. Please indent properly and remove unneeded blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the order you're linking the scripts, jquery should be before you like any file using jquery

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/json.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js"></SCRIPT>
```

Also, don't use onclick use:

```
$('#field').click(function(){
   test();
});
```

Comment: rearranging helped to remove the error that i mentioned, but the callback is still not fired.

Comment: I used the method you said by wrapping it around $.function(){}, but the result is same.. The callback doesn't fire. It goes back to the action class. Can there be anything to do with the struts xml ??

Comment: this '<s:textarea id="sub" name="tes"></s:textarea>' should contain the value from the json, i.e,. in this context "hello" in the testarea. I am trying to display that. Its not working.

Comment: Were you saying about $('#field').click(function()) execution? If yes, then I have already told you, that I have made it to work by wrapping it around $(function()) as you have done. Now, I am intending to invoke callback function. That cannot be determined by what you have shown. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery library should be called before anything else. Looks like the scripts are out of order from first glance. Try re-arranging the scripts and put the jquery.js first.

Comment: Try $.post('some.url', input, somecallback(json){ return true; }

Comment: did you mean like this?   $.post('some.action',input,somecallback(displaying){return true;});

Comment: Did u try it with json like the first example I gave u? The callback function needs to know what kind of data its expecting back.

Comment: $.post('some.action',input,somecallback(json){return true;}) and $.post('some.action',input,somecallback(json){return true;} both doesn't work.. It gives 'Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation'..

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue. These are the two changes that led me to the solution.

1) As it was mentioned above by adam and charles, the jquery.js should be above any other javascript to be loaded.

2) The jquery javascript I was using was 1.2.3 version, which did not support what I wanted to achieve, so I downloaded the latest i.e,. version 1.6.2, this actually supported what I wanted.

Thank you.